# Django Rest Framework add page number attribute using the PageNumberPagination class

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am building an API using Django and Django rest framework and I am trying to add the page number on the json results. And I am trying to add the page number in the returned results for example, I am currently getting this;

```
{
  "links": {
    "next": null,
    "previous": null
  },
  "count": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/brands/1/?format=json",
      "name": "microsoft",
      "description": "Nothing",
      "top_brand": true,
      "guid": "microsoft"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am trying to get something like this;

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/brands/1/?format=json",
      "name": "microsoft",
      "description": "Nothing",
      "top_brand": true,
      "guid": "microsoft"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "page_number": 1,
  "from": 1,
  "to": 10,
  "last_page": 4
}
```

The most important attribute is the page_number but I am not so sure how to get that from the parent class using `self...` I see no direct way besides using a function. Here is my code;

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data,
            'page_number': self.page.paginator...,
        })
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use your custom pagination in viewset and changed on custom view

**pagination.py**

```
class CustomPageNumber(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(OrderedDict([
             ('lastPage', self.page.paginator.count),
             ('countItemsOnPage', self.page_size),
             ('current', self.page.number),
             ('next', self.get_next_link()),
             ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
             ('results', data)
         ]))
```

In your view

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['get'], url_path='get-records/(?P<pk>[^/]+)')
    def get_record(self, request, pk):
        self.pagination_class = CustomPageNumber
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.queryset.filter(course=pk))
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and you need configure in your settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.apps.core.pagination.CustomPageNumber',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

If you want know more refer the docs [custom-pagination-class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#using-your-custom-pagination-class)

Comment: here one mistake in def get_paginated_response's  Response...in response " last_page : self.page.paginator.count "  is not given a total count of page...it will give you total records which will fetch.

Comment: It would be better to use `("countItemsOnPage", self.get_page_size(self.request))` instead. If the query includes a page_size parameter like `&page_size=5`, that should be reflected in the response, rather than always `2`.

Comment: I stumbled onto this trying to get current page and last page on my pagination. This actually worked, but there is just one small problem. The last page doesn't actually get the last page. To accomplish this, I just did last_page = math.ceil(self.page.paginator.count / self.page_size) then in Response ('last_page', last_page), . Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

if i understand you correct you can use `self.page.number`

```
    return Response({
        'links': {
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link()
        },
        'count': self.page.paginator.count,
        'results': data,
        'page_number': self.page.number,
        #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this to get the `to` and `from` might be more applicable:

```py
class MyCustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_from(self):
        return int((self.page.paginator.per_page * self.page.number) - self.page.paginator.per_page + 1)

    def get_to(self):
        return self.get_from() + int(len(self.page.object_list)) - 1

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):

        return Response({
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'page_number': self.page.number,
            'per_page': self.page.paginator.per_page,
            'from': self.get_from(),
            'to': self.get_to(),
            'results': data
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this was answered, there's a new component that takes a :number-of-pages property.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination-nav

Answer (score -1):

to disply the currnet page number in your response
basically you can do that on your views.py file
by create a custom 'pagination_class ', as the following.

i have model calls 'Comment' ,
note : this is just example , and change it based on your requirements :

```
## view all comments with Custom paganation ##
class MyCustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'page_number': self.page.number,
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'results': data,
        })




class C_ApiCommentListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = App1CommentSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    pagination_class = MyCustomPagination
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ('COM_comment', 'COM_title', 'COM_user__username')
```

i hope this helpful for you.